# only pass certain properties of jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jquery documentation for `.on()` says that it works pretty well for things that don't happen that often such as `"click"` (as opposed to things are pretty heavy, like `mousemove`), it gets more expensive to process.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").on("mousemove", "#div1", function (event){
    console.log(event);
  });
});
```

I was looking at the event that jquery passes when I make this mouse motion and notice it's very large. It contains a lot of information I will probably never use. Is it possible to only pass certain parts of that event and make it less expensive to process mouse movements or keypresses for example?

```
 //somehow only pass these properties?
 var desired_events = ["clientX", "clientY", "offsetX", "offsetY"];
```

http://jsbin.com/ofawom/1/edit

Comment: No. jQuery will always put all properties on its event object, and you cannot suppress that. Anyway, this should not be responsible for for the expensiveness of mousemove events. If you have performance problems (and only then), please show us your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this deals with the direct implementation/API of JQuery.
I'm afraid, whatever is implemented to be returned for an event will be returned within the event object.

See: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

According to that link:

> The following properties are also copied to the event object, **though
>   some of their values may be undefined depending on the event**:
>
> altKey, bubbles, button, cancelable, charCode, clientX, clientY,
>   ctrlKey, currentTarget, data, detail, eventPhase, metaKey, offsetX,
>   offsetY, originalTarget, pageX, pageY, prevValue, relatedTarget,
>   screenX, screenY, shiftKey, target, view, which

So, unless you use a custom implementation of JQuery, or over-ride the JQUERY  implementation/code with your own I don't see how you could make event object contain less.